# Does Recaptcha v3 show graphical captchas at all?

Tags: recaptcha, captcha

I currently use invisible recaptcha and it automatically shows a captcha if it thinks the user is a bot.

Now there is Recaptcha v3 and I struggle to understand how it is supposed to be used.

It returns a score, but what if the score is low which may indicate the user is a robot. Should I then show the graphical captcha by calling some function? Or should I simply pop up a dialog that captcha thinks you're a bot and that's it?

So what I don't get: what should happen if the user gets a low score? Is there a way for the user to still proceed by solving a captcha? Or is it the end of the road then and there is no way to go forward?

Does/can recaptcha v3 show graphical captchas to solve at all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The idea is no user friction, and displaying a captcha runs contrary to that. Recall that you should put ReCaptcha v3 on all pages, not only on those you want to protect: that’s how the captcha will learn to distinguish normal from abusive behaviors. A user must be *always* allowed to proceed. *Low scores should be used to prioritize or further qualify requests.*

For example, in analytics you may want to discard bot/scraper interactions with low scores. In commerce, you want to deprioritize bot orders – don’t count them in day’s sales, put them last in the queue and require human verification on your end, or an additional verification step i.e. an email challenge. In logins, low scores would force 2nd factor verification step. And so on – your question cannot be further answered without knowing the exact use for the page you ask about.

Comment: Ah, so in v3 no captcha should be shown at all. On my page there are multiple links which run certain heavier computations, so I don't want a bot (or a crazy user) to click all the links. For this reason I currently run invisible recaptcha before running a computation behind a llink, because it only allows the operation to run if the user is either not a bot or passed the captcha. So a lower score does not really help me here, because if the score is low I still have to make sure the user is not a bot (passes the captcha), I only want to run it if the user passes the test.

Comment: A low score means you should re-authenticate the user, for example. Using visible captcha won’t be enough at that point: low score means that things aren’t right and without a strong indication that a human is present, you can simply discard the request. Showing a visible captcha will likely get answered by a human captcha farm, or something like that, and certainly won’t shield you from bots. Recaptcha v2 is susceptible to human captcha farms. Those are cheap and in widespread use. When v3 fails, you know that captcha has failed: further use of catcha is opening up doors to bots.

Comment: @KubaOber "Recaptcha v2 is susceptible to human captcha farms." How does v3 get around it? Presumably a human looks like a human to reCaptcha v3, otherwise it's not working!

Comment: "displaying a captcha runs contrary to that"... but [this](https://product.hubspot.com/blog/quick-guide-invisible-recaptcha) seems to mention, under the Personalization > "type" heading that challenges will be shown. Perhaps v3 only means no initial tick box?

Comment: "A user must be always allowed to proceed." What if this is a "sign in" action?

Answer (score 1):

Giving the users a second chance, by presenting them graphical captcha challenges, defeats the purpose of using Recaptcha v3. Evil AIs are getting cleverer these days, they will simply solve the graphic type captcha and get to keep spamming your server.

Making it the end of the road is not good either, this might block legitimate users.

What you should do is, you make your users verify their identities through other means. You can send them messages through email or any other messaging services, and tell them to enter the code in a text box you provided. If they entered wrong code once (or twice, your choice), you can block them from accessing your app for five minutes (again, your choice).

Comment: Well, that works all good and dandy until someone tries to abuse your registration page with 30k stolen email addresses, and your email provider bans you from sending more emails.

Comment: @RobinJonsson Well, I was talking about using recaptcha to safe guard user login. In this case, we already have user's good email and phone number. Also they can't just keep asking us to send OTP, we can always limit them. In case of user registration, we can simply prevent each ip address from signing up too many times. What if the attacker took control a hundred thousand of remote machines with different IP adress, you ask? Well, that is outside the scope of this conversation; because even huge companies will have problem against such a huge scale attack.

Comment: Using a reputable third party's help might be a good solution, if you got attacked a lot. For example: Cloudflare...