# Google ReCaptcha Never Shows Puzzles

Tags: recaptcha, captcha

For our use-case, reCaptcha v3 or Enterprise does not work, please don't downvote without actually reading the question:

We have been using Google ReCaptcha v2 for some time with the goal of preventing human users who are idle from using Auto Clickers / Macros to cheat and level up in our web based game while they are away. For example, they run auto-clickers / macros to move their character and level up while they are away but their browsers are real and pass v3 and enterprise background captcha checks instantly because they are actually active in their browser maybe half of the day. While away, they run these auto-clicker tools to continue leveling up.

For this reason, we still use captcha v2, as it is the only option which has a graphical challenge which trips up auto-clickers, macros, and users trying to avoid becoming idle while they are away (to continue leveling up in our games).

Our issue is that reCaptcha v2 does not show graphical challenges to 99% of users, as it passes them silently and returns "No Challenge" making it essentially silent, and just as bad for us as v3 or enterprise.

To clarify, background (silent) non-graphical captchas such as v3/enterprise do not work for us, as they will pass 99% of the time for our users. These are human users with real browser sessions, they have just been idle for a few hours and are running auto-clickers while they are away. When we detect them, we want to display a captcha. For this reason we (along with almost all AAA gaming companies) still use reCaptcha v2, as it is the only option google offers that has a graphical / puzzle based captcha.

We only show a captcha to users who we are almost positive are cheating, so we are ok if it is very difficult.

hCaptcha has an option to "Force Challenge", which makes every single user get the graphical challenge for every captcha request. Does Google ReCaptcha (any version) have this option? Which forces a graphical challenge for each captcha? This is what we are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to v3 :) v3 came up because v2 was relatively easy to hack with ia the method you mentioned, and generally weak. That's why it hasn't been, most likely, updated for new strategies of robots.

When you do the switch, you'll be able to set the minimum trustworthiness threshold in reCAPTCHA v3 admin console.

Comment: But V3 does not show a graphical challenge at all, so I am not sure how it can tell if someone is idle. It seems like only a background bot check, so it is much worse for our use case, that is why almost no games use v3 or enterprise. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465827/does-recaptcha-v3-show-graphical-captchas-at-all

I found out today that hcaptcha has an option to "Always Challenge". I am wondering if reCaptcha has anything similar for any graphical captcha which requires user input and also checks if they are inactive / scripting.

Comment: So is the answer that you can't force a graphical challenge to all users using any version of Google ReCaptcha? Upgrading to a background based check only makes things worse in our case, as it does not catch users using real browsers but autoclickers.